# Find the relative minimum, Relative maximum, and point of inflection

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find the relative minimum, Relative maximum, and point of inflection:

$$ f(x)= \frac{x^3}{x^2-64} $$

Please elaborate on the points of inflection and chart of signs, because I did that and I got two inflection points and the question asks for one. Thanks.

Comment: It would improve your Question if you gave more detail about which two points you found were inflection points (and why).

Comment: I did a quick second derivative and got that the only places where *the function is defined* and the second derivative changes sign is $x=0$.

Comment: Could You add the first and second derivative in your question?

Answer (score 0):

First calculate

\begin{align}
f'(x) = \; \frac{x²(x²-192)}{(x²-64)²} , \;\;\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;\;\;
f''(x) = \;\frac{128x(x²+192)}{(x²-64)³}.
\end{align}

Also, observe that the function is discontinuous at $-8$ and $8$.

---

**Points of Inflection**

*Definition:* A point of inflection is a point at which the curve is continuous and changes from being concave $f''(x)<0$ to convex $f''(x)>0$ or vice versa.

Next, notice that

\begin{align}
f''(x)>0,& \;\; \text{for all }\; x \in (-\infty,-8) \cap (0,8) \\[2ex]
f''(x)<0,& \;\; \text{for all }\; x \in (-8,0) \cap (8,\infty)
\end{align}
So, there is one inflection point at $0$.

---

**Maxima and Minima**

A similar analysis for the first derivative yields

\begin{align}
f'(x)>0,& \;\; \text{for all }\; x \in (-\infty,192^{\frac{1}{2}}) \cap (192^{\frac{1}{2}},\infty) \\[2ex]
f'(x)<0,& \;\; \text{for all }\; x \in  (-192^{\frac{1}{2}},-8) \cap (-8,0) \cap (0,8)\cap (8,192^{\frac{1}{2}})
\end{align}

Notice that the function converges to $-\infty$ from the left and $\infty$ from the right as it approaches $-8$ or $8$. Moreover, it has one local (relative) maximum at $-192^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and one local minimum at $192^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: Thanks! Can you find the Relative Max & Min please?

Comment: @JaimeAguilar Please notice the changes in the answer. It turns out that discontinuity points are not considered inflection points usually, so I correct that.